# Set Dynamic text in ImageView cornor in android

Tags: android, textview, imageview

How to set dynamic text in imageview corner with different color in listitem

See old image[image]

Currently using static image.

Any sample code or suggestions library

Thanks,
Rajesh R

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use :

- `View.setRotation()` with your TextView, but you will still face the issue for drawing the blue triangle
- `Canvas`, you may draw anything as you like. [More informations about Canvas](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

Comment: For `setRotation()`, you only have to call the method.